# Uninstall laptop screen, replace with external monitor

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, bios, dell-inspiron

So as the title states, I took off the display panel on my Dell N4010 and replaced it with an HP LE1901w external monitor because I didn't feel like purchasing a $50+ LCD screen (Got the monitor for $9 at Goodwill). I also removed the CD Drive (don't ever use it) and placed the WiFi antenna where it was located, but that works well. [image: ([picture][1])]

Anyways, because I did that, a few problems came up.

First, when I boot up my laptop, it does 8 consecutive beeps and then starts over to warn about display failures, even though I have the external monitor hooked up. Is there any way to turn this off? I've checked the BIOS settings and I don't see anything about any chimes, beeps, or default displays.

Also, the "Starting Windows" splash screen is off center, as well as the BIOS some times. Auto-Adjusting the monitor only helps with the BIOS, but the splash screen still pushes to the left. It's very noticeable and I wanted to know if there's a fix for it.

Finally, my computer still recognizes the laptop's built in display. I've tried disabling it in the device manager, but I wasn't able to get a permanent fix. For the monitor to work properly, I have to enable the "Projector only" display setting with the F2 Key or the graphics options. Is there any way to completely uninstall the laptop's monitor? Even my Linux install recognizes the laptop's monitor.

One last thing, it would be nice to control the monitor's brightness with the laptop's brightness keys. I know I can control the monitor's brightness along with other settings with the Intel Graphics Properties [image: ([picture][2]),]

so I don't think it should be too hard to re-configure the keys to do the same.

I'd really appreciate a some suggestions. If you need any more information, just ask.

EDIT: New problem just popped up, GRUB2 is off center as well and auto-adjust doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

You computer, being a notebook, was made to use an LCD screen attached to it's motherboard. Your extenal monitor is, and will always be, the second monitor (until the drivers take care of it). So it's natural that the boot sequence and the boot screen show up incorrectly, because of the metrics of your second monitor being different to that of the original lcd screen. I've had this issue too and, as far as I know, there's nothing you can do about it. As far as the screen works well once the drivers have been loaded, there shouldn't be any problem with it.